# Layout in android N

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-intent

I have a basic question on how to arrange three activities on Screen at same time.

Here is my specific question - 
Based on what I read from Google's android documentation that single Activity covers the entire screen at one time. I want to create three activity like below

---

```
                         Notification_bar( first activity)
```

---

```
                         Main section of App (second activity)
```

---

```
                         Footer section (third activity)
```

---

I know I can achieve this by using three Layouts and it should be fine. I'm asking for activity for a reason and the reason is that "Main section (second activity)" will be used for several app (e.g. media player or whether) . In other word I'm trying to combine two or more application e.g. media & whether in a single app and both app will have it's separate service thread.

I'm preferring this design because unlike app launcher where user can import the installed app/apk into their activity and launch it from launcher activity. In the launcher based design it does not have control over the life cycle of imported apps process & activity (correct me if you think otherwise) and I do not want to choose where I don't have controls over child process and their activity. Also it slows down the app launch/visible time.

In above design (3 activities on screen) the Main process can control the life cycle of each activity and I can build a activity controller in main process who controls the activity life cycle. Of course each activity will run in main process but will have separate service thread to serve their purpose.

Feel free to comment about another design strategy if you have. Thanks in advance for your suggestion.

Comment: You don't have to create three activities for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already acknowledge that an activity consumes the screen. You should use 3 Fragments inside of your activity. A Fragment is really a View with extra meat and bones. Your activity layout should have a LinearLayout as the root and 3 Layouts as children which will serve to be the containers for the Fragments.

Comment: Hello apelsoczi, Thanks for the answer..I read about Fragments and that answer my above question. In Fragments do you know if we can create a parent child relation.. e.g. in html if we create two <div> say parent & child <div> if we hide parent <div> , all the child nodes associated with parent will be hidden. Do we have any thing similar in Fragments? or does this question make sense at all?

Comment: Please mark my comment as the answer to this question, it is required on stackoverflow - so that the question is no longer unanswered. For your next thought, within the parent view you simply call View.INVISIBLE or View.GONE

Answer (score 0):

[With reference of this,](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html) An Activity is an application component that provides a screen with which users can interact in order to do something, such as dial the phone, take a photo, send an email, or view a map. Each activity is given a window in which to draw its user interface. The window typically fills the screen, but may be smaller than the screen and float on top of other windows.

So, one time you can open only one activity.If app do not covers whole window then you can partially show below activity but can not perform any action from there with go that activity.